# How do I install QEMU 3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, qemu

I am using a Ryzen processor and, as such, I have been told that I need to use QEMU 3.0 for the SMT patch.

The issue is that I cannot seem to find any way to install it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS at all. It's not in the repositories, obviously; but, there are also no other PPAs or anything similar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that we need to compile [QEMU 3.0.0](https://www.qemu.org/download/#source) manually.

At first we remove version installed from official repository (if any):

```
sudo apt-get purge "qemu*"
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

We should start by installing its build-dependencies - at first enable *Source Code* repositories in *Software and Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and then:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qemu
```

Then download it, configure and compile:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-3.0.0.tar.xz
tar -xf qemu-3.0.0.tar.xz
cd qemu-3.0.0/
./configure
make
```

and then use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall):

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall make install
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

if you want to remove it - remove its packages as usual.

---

And as the result you will have QEMU 3.0.0 installed

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 3.0.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Comment: I ended up doing this but you should probably mention that on ubuntu you should use checkinstall instead of make install, because that packages it as a .deb and adds it to the package manager

Comment: You are completely right about `checkinstall`. *New contributor* badge forced me to lower my knowledge and skills ;)

Comment: In some shells `sudo apt-get purge "qemu*"` should be used *with the quotes*, or related packages will not be removed.